# What kind of numbers are inside a generating open interval of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, borel-sets

If it is enough to have all open intervals (a,b) with end points $a$ and $b$ belonging to the rational numbers, a < b, in order to generate a Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. Asked here:  [About the open intervals generating a Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3185497/about-the-open-intervals-generating-a-borel-sigma-algebra-on-mathbbr)

What kind of numbers do you need to have between $a$ and $b$? Only rational numbers or real numbers? And why?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Let's write $(a,b)_{\mathbb{Q}} = \{ t \in \mathbb{Q} : a < t < b\}$.  Are you asking whether the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{(a,b)_{\mathbb{Q}} : a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$?  The answer is no.

Comment: @NateEldredge My doubt was whether $ t \in \mathbb{Q} : a < t < b $ belongued to the rational numbers or the real numbers. I thought that open intervals with rational endpoints had to contained only rational numbers. So for what you said it has to contain real numbers in order to generate the σ-algebra on R?

Comment: By open intervals $(a,b)$ with rational end points what is meant is the set of all **real** numbers lying between the rational numbers $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy is it alway like that? I mean if I want to denote an open set with rational endpoints, and only rational numbers inside then do I need to use a special notation like Nate Eldredge did?

Comment: Yes. Since we are considering Borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb R$ it is understood that $(a,b)$ is interpreted ads real numbers between $a$ and $b$. If you want to consider only rational numbers you have to specify it, as done by Nate Eldredge.

Comment: One last doubt: Why can't you generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ with $(a,b)_{\mathbb{Q}} = \{ t \in \mathbb{Q} : a < t < b\}$. You can obtain the irrational numbers with the complements, then you have all the real numbers.

Comment: How would you show that $\{\sqrt 2\}$ belongs to your sigma algebra?

Comment: Using the complement of the open interval (1,2).((1,2) is made up of rational numbers only).

Comment: @Andrés E. Caicedo Why did you remove the question from the set-theory and descriptive-set theory subforums?  Open sets and Borel sets are part of these subjects.

Comment: Only in the same sense that any time you use the number 1 you are doing number theory. The question you are asking does not qualify.

Comment: If anyone can explain why a Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ can't be generated using only rational numbers, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Nate Eldredge, I'll write "$(a,b)_{\mathbb{Q}}$" for $(a,b)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ (with $a<b$ reals; note that we *don't* need $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ themselves for this to make sense). And I'll reserve "$(a,b)$" for the full interval of **real** numbers, as usual.

Now the key point is that **each $(a,b)_\mathbb{Q}$ is countable**. This implies that every element $X$ of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by such intervals is either countable or co-countable (= has countable complement). Specifically, let $\mathfrak{S}$ be the set of all sets of reals which are either countable or co-countable; it's easy$^1$ to check that $\mathfrak{S}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and it clearly contains each $(a,b)_{\mathbb{Q}}$.

- *Note $1$*: I'm not saying,incidentally, that $\mathfrak{S}$ **is** the $\sigma$-algebra so generated, merely that it **contains** it. Indeed, they're not the same, and it's a good exercise to find something in $\mathfrak{S}$ that isn't in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $(a,b)_\mathbb{Q}$s.
- *Note $2$*: More generally, it's usually the case that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a collection of "small" sets consists entirely of "small" or "co-small" sets; e.g. every element of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the null sets is either null or co-null, every element of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the meager sets is either meager or co-meager, etc.

But there are plenty of Borel sets which are neither countable nor co-countable - for example, the interval $(0,1)$.

---

$^1$OK, let's sketch that here.

Complements are immediate: if $A$ is countable (respectively co-countable) then $A^c$ is co-countable (resp. countable).

Countable unions are just complements of countable intersections of complements, so the previous line shows that if $\mathfrak{S}$ is closed under countable intersections it's also closed under countable unions.

So suppose $A_i\in\mathfrak{S}$ for $i\in\mathbb{N}$. We want to show that $X=\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i$ is either countable or co-countable. There are two cases:

- If some $A_i$ is countable, then we can conclude that $X$ is countable; do you see why?
- So suppose each $A_i$ is co-countable. The complement of $X$ is the union of the complements of the $A_i$s, which is to say a countable union of countable sets; what does this tell you about $X$?

Comment: Indeed, the $\sigma$-field generated by all $(a,b)_\mathbb{Q}$ is even smaller than your $\mathfrak{S}$: it consists precisely of the subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ and their complements.  So for example the set $\{1/3, \pi\}$, while countable, is not in it.

Comment: @Noah Schweber  Thank you very much for your detailed answer. If I undertood it correctly, as the resulting $\sigma$-algebra only have countable and co-countable sets, it can't be a Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.is that right? About your questions I'm thinking about it. Thanks for all the comments too

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, of course, I didn't mean to imply that they were the same; fixing for clarity.

Comment: @roy212 I don't know what *a* Borel $\sigma$-algebra is, I just know what *the* Borel $\sigma$-algebra is - namely, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all the open intervals. And since open intervals aren't in general countable or cocountable, $\mathfrak{S}$ is indeed far from the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (and so a fortiori your $\sigma$-algebra is as well).

Comment: By "your $\sigma$-algebra, do you mean the one made up of rational numbers only?

Comment: @roy212 I mean the one generated by the $(a,b)_\mathbb{Q}$s. It's not quite right to say that it's made up of rational numbers only; a $\sigma$-algebra isn't made up of numbers, it's made up of *sets of* numbers. What is true is that it is *generated by sets containing* only rational numbers (although again that doesn't mean that all sets in the algebra only contain rational numbers).

Comment: About your first question "do you see why?" , not, really I don't. About the second question "What does this tell you about $X$? I guess that $X$ must be countable, but I'm not very sure of the reason why.

Comment: @roy212 Re: the first question, remember that intersections make things smaller: we'll always have (for example) $A_{17}\supseteq \bigcap_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i$. So if $A_{17}$ is countable, what can you say about the size of the necessarily-no-larger $\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i$?

Comment: Re: your second question, what do you know about the union of countably many countable sets? (This is the sort of thing which the complement of $X$ is.)

Comment: About the second question, that if the sets are disjoint, the union of countably many countably sets, is countable. So if the complent of $X$ is countable, does it mean that $X$ is countable?

Comment: @roy212 Disjointness has nothing to do with it - the union of countably many countable sets is always countable. Re: your second sentence, I think your second "countable" should be "**co-**countable," in which case that's right (if X and its complement were each countable, then $\mathbb{R}$ itself would be countable).

Comment: About the first questions all I can say is that $\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i$ is countable.

Comment: @roy212 Yup, assuming some $A_i$ is countable we know that $\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i$ is countable - which means it's in $\mathfrak{S}$! Which is what we wanted.